# Service Worker reload page on cache update

Tags: javascript, web-worker, service-worker, offline-caching

I am using React+Service Worker+[offline-plugin](https://github.com/willdurand/offline-plugin/blob/master/README.md) to create a Service Workerwith persistent caching for the website.

I want to tell the user when a new version is stored in cach and suggest to refresh the page but I don't know how to reference the Service Workerand what event I should listen to (Service Workeris created automatically by npm "offline-plugin").

Standard flow today:

1. Webmaster publish a site (V1)
2. User visits the website
3. He sees the website (V1) while Service Worker stores pages in persistent cache
4. Webmaster publishes a new version (V2)
5. User revisits the site seeing old version from persistent cache while web worker loading new version in the background (V2).
6. When the user will refresh the page he will see website version 2

New flow should be:

6. V2 loaded done in the background
7. A popup message tels the user to refresh the page to get the new version.

Comment: no enough details. by the way you can use onmessage event when you have result from webworker you can show an alert on click of alert reload the page

Comment: Hi I have updated the description.

Answer (score 5):

Service worker is a specialized form of a webworker.
When you registry a sw, like for example in serviceWorkerRegistry.js, you'll have access to several events.
e.g.

```
serviceWorkerRegistry.js:

if (!navigator.serviceWorker) return;

navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(reg) {
    if (!navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
      return;
    }

    if (reg.waiting) {
      console.log("inside reg.waiting");
      return;
    }

    if (reg.installing) {
      console.log("inside reg.installing");
      return;
    }

    reg.addEventListener('updatefound', function() {
      console.log("inside updatefound");
      let worker = reg.installing;
      worker.addEventListener('statechange', function() {

        if (worker.state == 'installed') {
          console.log('Is installed');
          // Here you can notify the user, that a new version exist.
              // Show a toast view, asking the user to upgrade.
              // The user accepts.
              // Send a message to the sw, to skip wating.
              worker.postMessage({action: 'skipWaiting'});

        }
      });
    });
  });

sw.js:
// You need to listen for a messages
self.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  if (event.data.action === 'skipWaiting') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});
```

Now the problem with offline plugin, is that it creates the **sw** for you, and in that way is harder to understand what the **sw** is doing.
I would say, it's better to create your own sw, this way you can understand better the functionality. [this](https://github.com/Hosar/sw-cache-plugin) plugin can help you with the cache.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the following link:
[Service Worker life cycle - updates](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/service-worker/lifecycle#updates)

You can also update your service worker manually by running something like:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then((reg) => {  
  // sometime later…     
  reg.update(); 
});
```

You can tell that you have a new version ready (and not yet activated) on the Service Worker's `install` event.
You know that you have a new version loaded in the handler of the service worker's `activate` event.